# change css through vb.net

Tags: css, vb.net, asp.net

I have a style.css file which gives a color the the body of every aspx page, since every page calls that css file. But in one page I need to change the color of body through vb.net code. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could set it as a style attribute of the body tag.

```
Me.Body.Style.add("background-color", "#FFFF00")
```

(assuming your body tag has an id and a runat="server" attribute)

Answer (score 2):

Give the `<body>` an `ID` and a `runat="server"` attribute, and then you can access it in the code behind.

for example:

```
<body ID="body" runat="server">
```

codebehind:

```
body.CssClass = "whateverYouWant"
```

Comment: Then, in style.css, body.whateverYouWant{background-color: Lime ;}